# Implementing a pipeline in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I need to regularly scrape a site for coupon codes, validate them, and send out notifications. Validation in slow, however, so I don't want that process to bog down the flow of my app. Ideally, the scraper shouldn't have to wait for validation to finish to pump out more results.

I imagine the flow of data looking like this:

```
SCRAPER --> \_/ <--> VALIDATOR <--> \_/ <--> NOTIFIER
```

In-between each stage is a queue containing intermediate results. Is this feasible to implement? Does it even make sense to do? Thanks!

Comment: ```Is this feasible to implement? ``` give it a whirl see what you come up with.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [check out asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), Python's asynchronous library.